# Making a pixel perfect printout of a web page (as seen on screen)

Tags: html, browser, printing-web-page

I would like to make a 'backup' of [this](http://petrisa.woimakas.fi/2011/07/22/solution-of-the-month/) web page, preferably in PDF format. Like a screenshot, read-only, for reference.

Trying to print the page into a PDF (OS X, Safari) causes weird printer layout handling, which is a stylesheet issue etc. Let's not go there. I want exactly what the browser shows on screen. Like a screenshot (which I could take, but is tedious since the page needs scrolling).

Safari allows for "Save as web archive", but I would prefer a portable single-file format s.a. PDF. Really - is there no way?

I was sure SO would have an answer to this. Did not find the question asked, yet.

**Addendum:** 
Found [this](http://c-command.com/scripts/eaglefiler/web-archive-to-pdf) but it requires a non-free [EagleFiler](http://c-command.com/eaglefiler/) software. Looks like the most promising approach, though.

**Addendum 2**
Thanks for all the great suggestions so far. I will keep this open until a true killer-of-them-all solution is found. That would be i.e. any of the major browsers allowing true save-as-PDF without rendering the page for a printer.

For now, my own solution is to keep .webarchive files. Actually, unlike I first though, they are single files which is good. Naturally, the solution is OS X specific.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using something like [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to render your entire document as an image, and then printing (or saving) that image.

Comment: html2canvas looks promising and is a feat in itself. But it fails to render some of the text right (overlaps words) - and how should I 'save as image' the contents of a canvas entry?

Comment: [This page](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) has a good example of how to do that.  In a nutshell, you can use `toDataURL()` to get an encoded representation of your current canvas state, and then you can add an image tag that displays it.  Then you can copy/save/manipulate that image as you would any other image.

Answer (score 2):

I went to http://www.capturefullpage.com and put in [your URL](http://petrisa.woimakas.fi/2011/07/22/solution-of-the-month/) and got [this image](http://www.capturefullpage.com/Temp/a252001e-8b8d-41ba-870b-87dca11dd5aa.jpg).

There are other web sites out there to do this as well.  Furthermore there are browser plugins so you don't need to depend on sites like these.

Comment: Thanks. That actually renders everything fine, though the font seems a bit vague compared to my browser's rendering. Seems to work. However, as a JPEG I would lack the ability to copy-paste text out of a screenshot (that PDF backup would grant) so I'm keeping the question open, for now.

Answer (score 1):

Paparazzi! allows you to capture a whole page as a picture from Safari.  Dunno if it's scriptable, but I guess you could fake it with AppleScript in any event.  http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060712064929281

Comment: The tool looks really good. If it did PDF I'd probably select this as the official answer. And, it's OS X specific which is not a problem for me, but for others may be. So the jury is still out - hopefully some browser coder falls onto this page and sees the need. :)

Comment: For a command line version (as referred to on the Paparazzi page): http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/ Also that is OS X specific.

Answer (score 0):

[PdfMyUrl.com](http://pdfmyurl.com/) looks like a nice online thing, with many options, but the options need payment. [Free Online URL to PDF Converter](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/free-online-pdf-converter.aspx) (nice name!) does what it says and is, well, free.